# Is there a parameter for cspack.exe that tells it to do faster compression?

Tags: azure, cspack

The Azure cspkg generation command `cspack` takes too long! It uses basically all of one core for a long time, and I suspect it is trying to compress all my files as much as possible. I would rather speed up the process, anyone know another way? (Other than the obvious having less crap in my worker role)